# Push retrieved objects to state in React only brings me the last one

Tags: reactjs, json, use-state, solana

I'm fetching data from a json. And i want to display that data in my React component.But every time I try to pass the objects that I return from the json to my state, it returns only one and delete the previous, instead of the entire elements inside the json.

This is my code.

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});

  const connection = new Connection("devnet");
  
  const { publicKey } = useWallet();
  
  useEffect(() => {
    (async () => {
      //if not public key, close
        if(!publicKey) return;
        //get tokens
        let response = await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(
          publicKey!, // owner here
          {
            programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
          }
        );
        response.value.forEach((e) => {
          const accountInfo = SPLToken.AccountLayout.decode(e.account.data);
          //get only tokens with value of 1
          if ( parseInt(`${SPLToken.u64.fromBuffer(accountInfo.amount)}`) === 1 ) {
            const tokenPublicKey = `${new PublicKey(accountInfo.mint)}`
            //get the metadata of each NFT
            const run = async () => {

              const ownedMetadata = await programs.metadata.Metadata.load(connection, await programs.metadata.Metadata.getPDA(tokenPublicKey));
              //get only tokens of the collection ...
              if (ownedMetadata.data.updateAuthority === "Address_authority") {
              //show the json data from arweave
              let url= ownedMetadata.data.data.uri;
              fetch(url)
              .then(res => res.json())
              .then((out) => {

                setState(prevState => {
                  // THIS IS NOT WORKING FOR ME :(
                  return {...prevState, ...out};
                });
              })
              .catch(err => { throw err });
            } 
          };
  
          run();
          }
        });
        
    })()
    }, [connection, publicKey]);

  console.log(state)
```

Comment: Possibly unrelated, but that's potentially a bunch of distinct state changes (however many elements there are in `response.value`). You might want to do all the fetching, then update state once.

Comment: Also note that `.catch(err => { throw err })` doesn't do anything useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{...prevState, ...out};` creates a new object, puts all of `prevState`'s own properties on the new object, then puts all of `out`'s own properties on the new object (overwriting the values from `prevState` if `prevState` also had properties with those names).

It sounds like you want an array, not a single object:

```
const [state, setState] = useState([]);
```

Then setting:

```
setState(prevState => [...prevState, out]);
```

---

Possibly unrelated, but that's potentially a bunch of distinct state changes (one for each element in `response.value`). Because the work is asynchronous, that could also result in a number of interim re-renders. Maybe you want that, but if you don't, you can do all the fetching and then update state once. Also, any time you're doing async work in a `useEffect`, you should allow for the possibility the effect's dependencies have changed in the meantime or the component has unmounted. Something like this (see `***` comments):

```
const [state, setState] = useState({});

const connection = new Connection("devnet");

const { publicKey } = useWallet();

useEffect(() => {
    // *** Use a controller to stop when the component unmounts, etc.
    const controller = new AbortContoller();
    const {signal} = controller;
    (async () => {
        if (signal.aborted) return; // ***

        // If not public key, stop
        if (!publicKey) return;

        // Get tokens
        let response = await connection.getTokenAccountsByOwner(
            publicKey!, // owner here
            {
                programId: TOKEN_PROGRAM_ID,
            }
        );

        // *** Build up the new data in this array (since we skip some elements,
        // so we won't have a simple 1:1 mapping of `response.value` elements
        // to result elements.
        const newState = [];
        // *** Wait for all the operations to finish and add their elements to `newState`
        await Promise.all(
            response.value.map(async (e) => {
                const accountInfo = SPLToken.AccountLayout.decode(e.account.data);
                // Skip tokens with value other than 1
                if (parseInt(`${SPLToken.u64.fromBuffer(accountInfo.amount)}`) !== 1) {
                    return;
                }
                const tokenPublicKey = `${new PublicKey(accountInfo.mint)}`;
                const ownedMetadata = await programs.metadata.Metadata.load(connection, await programs.metadata.Metadata.getPDA(tokenPublicKey));
                // Get only tokens of the collection ...
                if (ownedMetadata.data.updateAuthority !== "Address_authority") {
                    return;
                }
                // Show the data from arweave
                let url = ownedMetadata.data.data.uri;
                const response = await fetch(url, {signal}); // *** Pass the signal to `fetch`
                if (!response.ok) { // *** This check was missing
                    throw new Error(`HTTP error ${response.status}`); // Or ignore if you prefer
                }
                const out = await response.json();
                newState.push(out);
            })
        );
        // *** Now we have all of them, do one state update
        setState(prevState = [...prevState, ...newState]);
    })();

    return () => {
        // Stop if our dependencies change or the component unmounts
        controller.abort();
    };
}, [connection, publicKey]);
```

Comment: Even with that is it fine to setState inside a forEach multiple times after async calls. Isn't mapping all the promises and getting final result better?

Comment: @TusharShahi - It depends entirely on the use case, but [I raised that question as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70411499/push-retrieved-objects-to-state-in-react-only-brings-me-the-last-one/70411559?noredirect=1#comment124465858_70411499). :-)

Comment: Ok. I was of the impression something like this would not even work and have always mapped and then setState. Maybe it does work

Comment: @TusharShahi - It works because it's using the callback version of the state setter. But it queues a lot of state updates, and depending on the async timing potentially does rerenders as the results come in. Sometimes that's what you want, but often I'd say it isn't. :-)

Comment: @TusharShahi - I decided to add a bit about that.

Comment: This is much cleaner. I am so sorry. I spent over a week writing it and forgot the basics. Regarding the state, it is giving me an error. I assume it should be an arrow function right?: setState (prevState => [... prevState, ... newState]); Still, typescript flags me "Type '{}' is not an array type." on prevState

Comment: @NicolásChaccal - No worries! Did you change the initial value provided to `useState` to `[]` as shown above?

Comment: No, sorry. My state was const [state, setState] = useState({}); I already changed it to const [state, setState] = useState([]), but now typescript is giving me this error in the whole setState statement. "Argument of type '(prevState: never[]) => any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<never[]>'."

Comment: @NicolásChaccal - I just realized you said TypeScript. Nothing in your question mentions TypeScript, and the code ciearly isn't using any TypeScript annotations. Yes, you'd get that error with TypeScript because TypeScript can't infer the type of the array from an empty array, so it infers `never[]`. You'd have to give an appropriate type as a type argument, for instance `const [state, setState] = useState<Example[]>([]);` where `Example` is an object type that matches what you get from the `fetch`. (You'll need lots of other type annotations in that code.)

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I'm going to mark the answer as correct, because it actually works. And I'm going to check the array type for the state in Typescript. Thanks a lot!